# Vapor ratio vs Gas Ratio (Internal energy in container with VLE mixture)

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, evaporation

I have something that I can't manage to figure out.

If one has a system which contains a VLE mixture (saturated liquid + saturated vapor in equilibrium) and a gas (let's say air) in a closed container, the average internal energy of the mixture can be calculated by using the following formula:

> $u_{mix} = u_f + x (u_g - u_f)$

If one considers only the mixture, the vapor fraction can be defined as:

> $x = \frac{m_{vap}}{m_{mix}}$

But what happens if one has also air inside? How is x defined? Is it defined like this?

> $x = \frac{m_{vap}}{m_{tot}-m_{gas}}$, where $m_{tot}-m_{gas} = m_{mix}$

or

> $x = \frac{m_{vap}}{m_{tot}}$

The challenge here is given by the fact that the vapor and the gas occupy the same volume, which is what confuses me.

So which is more correct, to take the mass of the entire system or only the mass of the mixture when calculating the vapor fraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding VLE problems that deal with typical alkane hydrocarbons, the vapor pressure of the liquid is a function of temperature only, and is unaffected by the presence of air.  This can easily be seen in several ASTM tests of vapor pressure (e.g., Reid vapor pressure of gasoline), where the presence of air in the measuring apparatus is completely ignored, and liquid material evaporates until an equilibrium is established between the liquid in the container and the vapor in the container, regardless of ambient atmospheric pressure.  This implies that your calculation should deal with air separately from the "VLE" material, unless you are dealing with a material which has a fairly high propensity for dissolving air.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, David. Interesting information. I was thinking to ignore air and I have no problem doing that, but this assumption is reflected in the pressure. If one neglects the air, then the pressure inside equals the saturation pressure of the liquid, and it is therefore important. So would you say that for calculating the pressure, air should be considered, but neglected for the internal energy calculation?

Comment: @Paul, treat the air separately.  The air contains its own energy, and contributes to pressure via the ideal gas law.  The liquid inside the container also contributes to total pressure due to its vapor pressure.  The sum of air pressure and vapor pressure is total pressure.  The sum of the enthalpy of the air and the enthalpy of the liquid-vapor mixture is the total enthalpy of the system.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. It confirms my understanding. That's great. Thank you!